# Scipy Lagrange division by zero

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to interpolate a set of ordered pairs using Numpy's Lagrange Interpolation; I have done this before without incident.
This time, however, I keep getting "Division by zero error" and the interpolating polynomial comes out with infinite coefficientes.
I am aware data points must not be repeated due to the internal workings of Lagrange's  Method, and they are not repeated.

Here is my code and the offending ordered pair, in numpy vector format.
Code:

```
x = out["x"].round(decimals=3)
x = np.array(x)
y = out["y"].round(decimals=3)
y = np.array(y)
print(x)
print(y)
pol = lagrange(x,y)
print(pol)
```

Ordered pair:

```
[273.324 285.579 309.292 279.573 297.427 290.681 276.621 293.586 283.463
 284.674 273.904 288.064 280.125 294.269 288.51  285.898 273.419 273.023
 281.754 281.546 283.21  303.399 297.392 293.359 306.404 356.285 302.487
 280.586 299.487 302.487]
[ 0.     5.414  6.202  0.     9.331 11.52   0.    10.495  5.439  4.709
  0.     4.916  0.    10.508  6.736  5.25   0.     0.     6.53   4.305
  5.124  6.753 10.175 10.545  5.98   9.147 11.137  0.     8.764  9.57 ]
```

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you notice they caution against using any more than about 20 points?  You can imagine problems creating a 19th-degree polynomial.

Comment: As a side note, rounding destroys data, and is probably how you ended up with a duplicate.  You should always keep the full resolution, and only round when you PRINT the data.  After all, it's only humans who have an issue dealing with multiple decimal places.

Comment: Thanks to both for your input. I was not aware of said caution about not using it for more than 20 points. It does work for less than 20 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why Lagrange Interpolation did not work for you.

You have the value `302.487` twice in your array `x`. I.e. you did repeat it.

### Why Lagrange Interpolation is not what you want.

As Tim Roberts pointed out Lagrange interpolation is really not made for 20 points. The problem is that polynomials of high degree tend to overfit. Check out the following example from the [wikipedia article of overfitting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

[image]

> Figure 2.  Noisy (roughly linear) data is fitted to a linear function and a polynomial function. Although the polynomial function is a perfect fit, the linear function can be expected to generalize better: if the two functions were used to extrapolate beyond the fitted data, the linear function should make better predictions.

### Alternative Regression

There are at least two valid alternatives. One of them being what is recommended in the wikipedia article. If you know what type of function your data is ruffly coming from use regression to fit a function of that type to the data. In the case of the example above thats a linear function. If you want to do that check out [scipy's curve fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

### Alternative Spline Interpolation

An other alternative is spline interpolation. Again from the wikipedia article on [Spline Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)

> Instead of fitting a single, high-degree polynomial to all of the values at once, spline interpolation fits low-degree polynomials to small subsets of the values, for example, fitting nine cubic polynomials between each of the pairs of ten points, instead of fitting a single degree-ten polynomial to all of them. Spline interpolation is often preferred over polynomial interpolation because the interpolation error can be made small even when using low-degree polynomials for the spline. Spline interpolation also avoids the problem of Runge's phenomenon, in which oscillation can occur between points when interpolating using high-degree polynomials.

There are just two little technical details that I want to point out. Point one is you points need to be ordered so I did that for you. And two scipy's `UnivariateSpline` has a smoothing parameter `s` that you need to choose. If you pick it small it sticks to the data like you're used to with Lagrange interpolation but if you make it bigger it well becomes smoother and hopefully generalizes better. Below I picked 2 different values for you to look at but you should probably play around with it yourself. I included a very small one so you see it can do what you're used to from Lagrange interpolation but wouldn't recommend it. Also you probably should use more data, preprocess it etc.. But that's not what the question was about.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

idx = np.argsort(x)
x = x[idx]
y = y[idx]

for s in [10,60]:
    t = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 10**4)
    f = UnivariateSpline(x,y, s=s)

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(t,f(t))
    plt.title(f'{s=}')
    plt.show()
```

[image: s=10]
[image: s=60]